# Cypress and Kafka automation

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, automation, cypress

i was wonderring if is there some how to automate testing using cypress and apache kafka.
To be able to "get" a especific topic in a broker, send a topic (producer) and receive a topic (consumer), all this using cypress.
Any ideas how to start? or is not possible to do it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Isn't Cypress a frontend tool? If so, that's not going to work with Kafka

Comment: KafkaJS uses Jest for testing https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/master/types/tests.ts